# How to use .format(**dict) with a dictionary that gets updated in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, string.format

I am trying to do some map scraping and I fill the URL string with a parameter dictionary 'on the fly' like this:

```
par = {'zoom': 13, 'latmin': 2835, 'latmax': 2844, 'lonmin': 4464, 'lonmax': 4475, 'ext': 'png'}
url = 'https://some.url.com/{zoom}/{lat}/{lon}.{ext}'

for lat in range(par['latmin'], par['latmax']):
    par['lat'] = lat
    for lon in range(par['lonmin'], par['lonmax']):
        par['lon'] = lon
        url = url.format(**par)
```

The dictionary gets updated but for some reason the URL string is stuck at the first iteration. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote your format string (which contains placeholders for new values) with a *formatted* string (where the placeholders have been replaced with the data they were holding a place for). From the second iteration onwards, there is no `{lat}` or `{lon}` placeholder in the string. If you printed `url` immediately after the first inner loop ran, you'd see the contents were now:

```
url = 'https://some.url.com/{zoom}/2835/4464.{ext}'
```

which still has placeholders for `{zoom}` and `{ext}`, but has fixed values for the other placeholders, so there is nothing to update on future loops.

If you don't want that to happen, don't assign back to `url` after `format`ting, use a different name for the partially formatted string (or use a `list` of such partially formatted strings if you want one for every combination of `lat` and `lon`).